# ASP.NET Core targeting full framework with EF6 and Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I currently have a .NET Core Web App targeting the full .NET Framework and a .NET 4.6.1 class library project that contains my EF6 implementation.

I have these two currently working together.

Now I need to add Identity, but I need to customize the implementation. (If it matters, I'm building against an existing user table and only care about local logins)

So in the 4.6.1 class library project I've created the customized Identity classes/stores/managers using this guide: https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

The part I am stuck on is how to configure the .NET Core App to use the non-Core version of Identity.

All the tutorials have configs similar to

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(config => { })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

and

```
app.UseIdentity();
```

However both those methods only exist in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity and not Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, which is what the class library is using.

**What frameworks should the .NET Core App be referencing? And what should the Startup.cs configuration look like?**

To keep things simple, all my custom Identity code is exactly what's in the article linked above.

The Startup.cs code looks like this (with AspNetCore.Identity referenced)

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, CustomRole>(config => { /* config */ })
                .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
                .AddUserStore<CustomRoleStore>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Sample Controller

```
public AccountController(ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
}
```

Error when trying to run it

> InvalidOperationException: Type ApplicationUserManager must derive from UserManager.

Comment: After trying to find a solution for this exact problem, I've given up because the AddIdentity, UserManager, SignInManager are all implemented and dependant on AspNetCore.Identity. I believe to make this work with EF6 and EF6 Identity, you would need to roll your own SignInManager, RoleManager, and in my case, it is much simpler to just port my project to EF Core and Identity Core. If you ONLY need Dependency Injection, use the services.AddScoped instead of services.AddIdentity (since AddIdentity is defined in Identity Core).

Comment: Using EF6 in core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6

Comment: Porting to Identity Core : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/identity

Answer (score 0):

> However both those methods only exist in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity and not Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, which is what the class library is using.

You should strictly distinct two api : ASP NET Identity https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity and ASP NET Core Identity https://github.com/aspnet/Identity

> What frameworks should the .NET Core App be referencing?

ASP NET Core Identity (Microsoft.AspNetCore) should be referenced.

> And what should the Startup.cs configuration look like?

Since you want to use EF6 you will need to port "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" (https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/master/src/EF) to your own realization that uses EF6. After this you would need to provide your own `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<TDbContext>();` extension method. Therefore Startup.cs should left the same (except using, to reference AddEntityFrameworkStores you will need to point your ported lib namespace).